# How to cancel opening popup with beforeClose callback ? #magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I'm using a MagnificPopup with a beforeClose callback and I'd like to cancel its opening depending on a condition. How can I do that ?

I tried a return `false`, or a `$.magnificPopup.close();` but it still opens...

I'm sure there is a basic solution !

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or other self-contained example.

Comment: I tried eventHandler's solution, but it doesn't work. So I created a JSFiddle page : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/48Tge/2/) to show you

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky, but you can do it by opening the popup directly at initialization:

```
var popupDefaults = {
    type: 'inline',
    fixedContentPos: false,
    fixedBgPos: true,
    overflowY: 'auto',
    closeBtnInside: true,
}

$('.open-popup-link').on("click", function(){
    var condition = false;
    if(!condition){
      $(this).magnificPopup(popupDefaults).magnificPopup('open');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/Gw9q2/)

If you change the condition to `true`, the popup will not open.

Comment: if your condition is based on window.width, you could use disableOn: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#disableon

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to overwrite the javascript function that creates the popup if your condition is true. like:

```
var originalOpen = window.open;
if (condition) {
    //prevent open new window
    window.open = function(){return null;};
}

// after window open attempt
window.open = originalOpen
```

you could do this with alert, and any kind of message box.

another way would be to modify magnificPopup...

Answer (score 0):

Use **[disableOn](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#disableon)**

```
disableOn: function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(Optional): This won't stop the default behavior of the DOM element triggering the popup.

**If you're using an anchor tag that loads a Youtube video in a popup**:

- the disableOn will stop the popup from opening
- the browser will follow the URL of the anchor tag's href!

To stop this from happening, add an additional check on the DOM element's click handler:

```
// Stop an anchor tag's default behavior
// Otherwise if it's a Youtube video, clicking this DOM element will land users on Youtube
$("a.my-popup").on("click", function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){
        return false;
    }
});
```